# Unexpected response from NSFileManager in Sketch Plugin

Tags: cocoa, plugins, sketch-3

I published a Sketch Plugin with some functionalities with a strong dependency in files management.

When execute, plugin needs to check if a folder exists, if not, create, and then manage several files inside this directory.

Some weeks ago, one user reported plugin was crashing in a new Sketch version.

Unexpected response from:

- `fileExistsAtPath` return -folder does not exist- when actually exists in that path
- `createDirectoryAtPath` return 'error' when trying to create a non-existing folder (I've tested both when folder exists and not)

Quick example:

**Request**

```
var document = context.document
var documentName = document.displayName()
var documentFolderPath = decodeURIComponent(document.fileURL()).replace('file:///','').replace(documentName,"")

print(documentName)
print(documentFolderPath)

var translationsFolderName = documentName.replace('.sketch','_translations')
var translationsFolderPath = documentFolderPath+translationsFolderName+'/'

print(translationsFolderName)
print(translationsFolderPath)

var fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:translationsFolderPath isDirectory:'YES'])
{
   print(translationsFolderPath+" folder does not exist")
   if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:translationsFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:'YES' attributes:nil error:nil])
    {
       print(translationsFolderPath+" folder can't be created")
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
test.sketch
Users/myuser/Documents/
test_translations
Users/myuser/Documents/test_translations/
Users/myuser/Documents/test_translations/ folder does not exist
Users/myuser/Documents/test_translations/ folder can't be created

Script executed in 0.034733s
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file path is not rooted (doesn't start with /)

Comment: fixed with / at the beginning, but very weird... plugin was tested before and working without that

Comment: Testing in Xcode will not always reveal this sort of issue. Your app starts in a different directory within the file system.